# Count variable for unbalanced panel data, repeating the last value conditioned on a binary variable

Tags: count, binary, conditional-statements, stata, panel-data

I am having a hard time generating a count variable `count = _n` for  unbalanced panel data with the following conditions in Stata:

Starting counting (from `_n`) every time the binary variable is equal 1, if it changes from 1 to 0, then `count` repeats the last value until the binary changes to 1 again (in this case keep counting from where it stopped).

I think it is much easier to show my problem giving an example of my dataset:

```
year    country  binary  count[variable that I want to create]
1959        1       0       0
1960        1       0       0
1961        1       1       1
1962        1       1       2
1963        1       1       3
1964        1       0       3
1965        1       0       3
1966        1       .       .
1967        1       1       4
1959        2       0       0
1960        2       0       0
1961        2       0       0
1962        2       1       1
1963        2       1       2
1964        2       .       .
1965        2       .       .
1966        2       0       2
1967        2       0       2
1968        2       1       3
1969        2       1       4
1970        2       0       4
1959        3       1       1
1960        3       1       2
1961        3       1       3
1962        3       0       3
1963        3       .       .
1964        3       1       4
1965        3       .       .
1966        3       0       4
```

In the above example, for `country = 1`, my new variable `count` starts counting (from `_n`) at the year 1961 (because for this year, the binary variable is equal to 1), then it counts (from `_n`) until `binary = 0` again (keeping the same last `count` number).

Missing values are kept as missing values in the new variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the data you show, the following creates `ncount` which matches your values of `count`.

```
bysort country (year): generate ncount = sum(binary)
replace ncount = . if missing(binary)
list, sepby(country)
```

Comment: William's excellent solution can be condensed to `bysort country (year) : generate ncount = cond(missing(binary), ., sum(binary))`.